# I try to load new values in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector don`t update with new values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a function witch find web elements with selenium driver.When I run on the first go its find elements and its ok on second go after page is changed Its return the same values like the first go.Why cause this I can`t find solution online.

```
def first():  
    driver.current_url
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1500)")
    time.sleep(5)
    post_to_comment = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.kIKUG')
    # do something after its call from a while loop its skip this.
first()
while n < 10:
   driver.get(new_url)
   n += 1
   first()
```

Comment: I think you need to post more code... this looks like a short version... and what is the point of this line?: driver.current_url

Comment: i try to switch to current page if the driver if its on the last one but its pointles.Its just givin me old result.

Comment: I think all that does is get the current url, but you don't even assign a variable there.   Problem could be that you are getting the same URL?  Or the lack of webdriverwaits, or checks for stale element exceptions.  (if sleep period is not long enough)  You should try/catch your calls on the post_to_comment webelement array to see if you find stale element exception.  The first sleep may not be necessary, btw.  (depends on if the site is "lazy loading".)

Comment: Looks like you keep loading the same page over and over, tell it to scroll but keep selecting the same first element.  Maybe post the website, or some HTML for further input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I did not set n to 0 after first go of the while loop and the program don`t enter in the while because n is > than 10.So the problem is not related to selenium.